# Adding validation method on the 'Done' button added to the UITextField input method

Tags: ios, validation, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I am trying to valide the input in the UITextField when the added 'Done' UIBarButtonItem is pressed, but since its target is set to UITextField i am editing, I cannot call the custom validation method.  Does anyone have idea how to fix this?
I have tried to add the custom method by replacing "resignFirstReponder" with validateInput(a custom method), but it throws an exception error as the target, textField, does not have the called method, I presume.  If I set the target to 'self', then it won't add the 'done' button to the UITextField.  please help.

Sorry I didn't put the whole code. Here is the whole code around this functionality:

```
- (void) addDoneButton: (UITextField *) textField
{
    UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone                                                                                 target:textField action:@selector(resignFirstResponder)];
    UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    toolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObject:barButton];

    textField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar;    
}

- (void) viewDidLoad{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self addDoneButton:txtBox];    
 }
```

Comment: Hey this is not the way you do it, please post the kind of UI you need and the functionality you want. There are lot of mistakes in your code.

Comment: Thank you.  I see your point.  I edited the code. Is this okay?

Answer (score 0):

Just set the action on your `barButtom` property:

```
[barButton setAction:@selector(myValidationMetod)];
```

Use any validation on the textField inside that method.

Answer (score 0):

Target should be self I guess and action:@selector(yourCustomMethod).

```
-(void)yourCustomMethod
{
  if(textField.length>0)
     {
       NSLog(@"textField Validated");
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will need to make my custom method to validate the input.  It's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

What you'll need to do is make the done button call a method on the controller, which will then be responsible for validating the `text` and calling `resignFirstResponder`.

That will look like this

```
UIBarButtonItem *barButton =
  [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
                                                target:self
                                                action:@selector(doneTapped)];

UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
toolbar.items = @[ barButton ];

self.textField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar;
```

Now you need to implement the `doneTapped` method

```
- (void)doneTapped
{
  [self.textField resignFirstResponder];

  NSString *text = self.textField.text;

  // validate text
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It's helpful, but I didn't ask my question correctly. So I updated my code to give more background.  If I set the target 'self' the 'done' button does not work...i guess I need to set the target to the UITextField I want 'done' button to be attached to.

Comment: Did you try this? The target needs to be set to the object that will handle the selector. In this case the viewController (self) is the object that handles the action not the textField

Comment: I tried it, but when I change the target to 'self', the 'done' button doesn't work.  I want the 'done' button used to dismiss the keypad. I think that is why the button does not do anything when i set the target to 'self.'  Shouldn't the target be the UITextField view since it only appears when the keypad appears?

Comment: Did you do call `resignFirstResponder` on the `textField` inside the `doneTapped` method?

Comment: yes, it throws "unrecognized selector sent to instance" Also, I want to reuse the addDoneButton method for other textfield. As far as I understand, the UIBarButtonItem cannot pass on arguements/parameters. Hm....

Comment: to doneTapped instance. It throws a SIGABRT error when pressed.

Comment: Can you show the exact error as that doesn't make sense it will normally be something like `-[Someclass doneTapped] ...`